# If $n^{\log n}$ is not polynomial or exponential, then what this function is called?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, polynomial-time

I just found this sentence on page 6 of Garey and Johnson's "Computers and Intractability".

> Any algorithm whose time complexity function cannot be so bounded is called an exponential time algorithm (although it should be noted that this definition includes certain non-polynomial time complexity functions, like $n^{\log n}$, which are not normally regarded as exponential functions).

My question as following,

If $n^{\log n}$ is not polynomial nor exponential, then what this function is called? Does this have a name or special cases or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no fixed terminology for these types of functions. You might sometimes see "subexponential" or "superpolynomial" used to refer to this kind of behavior.

Comment: Another common term is *quasipolynomial*.

Comment: @user777 I think subexponential is of form $$c^{n^{\frac1{1+\gamma}}}$$ while superpolynomial or quasipolynomial is of form $$c^{\log^{1+\gamma} n}$$ with $c,\gamma>0$ remaining fixed